# Not able to pass data from parent to child component in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-components

When I try to pass the data from the parent to the child component I get error.

This is the tag which I have placed it in the parent component.

```ts
<pop-up [showPopUp]="true" [content]="content" [title]="title goes here"></pop-up>
```

**Child component**

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'pop-up',
  templateUrl: './pop-up.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pop-up.component.css']
})
export class PopUpComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  showPopUp: boolean;
  @Input()
  title: string = "";
  @Input()
  content: string = "";

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    debugger;
  }
  proceed() {
    this.showPopUp = true;
  }
  closePopUp() {
    this.showPopUp = false;
  }
}
```

I want to use the variable `showPopUp`, title and content in the HTML like this

```ts
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{title}}</h5>
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{content}}</h5>
```

But when I try to use it, I get error 
[image]

I am not sure what exactly i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```ts
[title]="title goes here"
```

should be

```ts
[title]="'title goes here'"
```

or

```ts
title="title goes here"
```

Your original code tries to assign the value of the expression `title goes here` to `title`, but that is no valid expression.
You can make the expression a string literal, or remove `[]`, then Angular won't try to interpret the value as expression.

Comment: thank you, can i know the reason why it is taking the format like this

Comment: I added an explanation already in my answer (you might not have seen it yet because I edited my answer after my initial post). `[]` is special Angular binding syntax.